# Extracting a REST API error object, after a WebException has been thrown

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am currently working with a REST API (using WCF) where one of the requests may look similar to this:

```
DELETE http://<host>/restapi/<id>
```

Now, let's say `id` doesn't exist, the server would return

```
404 Not Found
```

Which is fine.

However, the REST API also provides me with a more specific error message.

Let's call it MyErrorClass:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.18020")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class MyErrorClass
{
    public string ErrorCode;
    public string ErrorDescription;
}
```

Even if I would set my ServiceContract to return an instance of this class, the WebException would be thrown before being able to evaluate it.

I am able to get the object by using

```
WebException -> Response -> GetResponseStream()
```

But it doesn't feel like the smoothest way.

Is there a way of getting MyErrorClass, without needing to parse the stream?

Comment: So I'm not sure I understand the question, is your question about reading the serialized exception from the **client** side of the WCF service?  Or a better way to create the WCF Service so as to avoid the `WebException` in the first place?

Comment: @CodingGorilla It's about finding a better way of reading the exception from the **client** side.

**Example 1**: This gives me an object that I can use without doing any parsing:

        `UserInformation GetUserInformation(long userId);`

**Example 2**: In this case, I would have parse the stream myself, instead of having an instance of it "good to go":

        `Stream GetUserInformation(long userId);`

It's the same thing with the error messages that comes from the REST service, I'll have to parse the stream instead of just receiving an object instance.

Comment: Have you looked at `HttpClient`, it's in the Microsoft.Net.Http nuget package.  It has a much better API for what you're wanting to do (IMO).  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx, https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/

Comment: @CodingGorilla I haven't, but I'll definitely check it out and see what I can do with it. Thanks!